# fiddler 4 doesn't start up at all, without out an error code

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler 4 is not opening up. I tried opening it, running it as an administrator and troubleshooting.

I installed it last week, and nothing was wrong then. I could use it until yesterday, when it wouldn't even start up. I didn't have any errors until it wouldn't start up.

I am trying to open it from cortana, the shortcut and in the programs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. How did you install the product, did you get any error messages at that point, and how are you trying to open it? Think how you would explain this problem to a coworker you were asking for help. At the moment we have nowhere near the amount of information that would let the community help you. Thanks.

Comment: Start a Windows command prompt, go to your Fiddler install directory (e.g. "d:\Program Files\Fiddler", and type `fiddler -?`.  This will print command line options.  Try some of them (e.g. `fiddler`, `fiddler -noscript -viewer -port 9999`, etc etc) to try isolating the problem.